# What is the optimal way to find out if ManyRelatedManager is an empty QuerySet in django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models, 
`Bacon` and `Eggs` that both have `ForeignKey` to `Spam` model.

I need to find out the Bacon's that are not related to `Eggs`, currently I'm doint it in the following way:

```
objs = Bacon.objects.select_related.filter(somefilter=value)

for obj in objs:
    if obj.spam.eggsspam.count():
        continue

    do_something()
```

I'm sure there must be a more optimal way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Bacon.objects.filter([m2m_field_name]__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). The code will look similar to this:

```
Bacon.objects.annotate(num_eggs=Count('spam__egg_set')).filter(num_eggs__eq=0)
```

Comment: @ChrisPratt's answer is simpler - but +1 still because I need the counts elsewhere.